# Excel: rows into columns by category

Tags: excel, categories, transpose

i have a excel sheet that looks like this:

```
Category    Value
X           1
X           2
X           3
X           4
Y           1
Z           1
Z           2
```

And I would like to transform it into categories and get value rows into columns. Like that:

```
Category    Value1    Value2    Value3   Value4
X           1         2         3        4
Y           1         
Z           1         2
```

Guys, any idea how to do it? I am really stuck with it.
many thanks.

Comment: You just need to use a pivot table and put the values into columns and categories in to the rows

Comment: Many thanks, however that does not work that way.

Comment: You can check my answer, but I m not sure what is not working for you

Answer (score 0):

If I m not mistaking you can simply use a pivot table:

It will make you pass from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

you just need to put the two columns in the rows columns and values as of below:

[image]

After that you can just change the names of your columns

Answer (score 0):

Walk up your data from the bottom to the top, reorganizing as you go.

```
Option Explicit

Sub expandValues()

    Dim i As Long, mx As Long, arr As Variant, tmp As Variant

    With Worksheets("sheet7")

        'determine no of values and create new headers
        For i = 1 To Application.Max(.Columns("B"))
            .Cells(1, i + 1) = "value" & i
        Next i

        'transfer values
        For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1
            If .Cells(i, "A").Value2 = .Cells(i - 1, "A").Value2 Then
                With .Range(.Cells(i, "B"), .Cells(i, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
                    .Parent.Cells(i - 1, 3).Resize(1, .Columns.Count) = .Value2
                End With
                .Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's  the formula approach ,

[image]

First write this array formula in cell C2 and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to find unique values from column A (i.e. X, Y, Z) and drag it down.

> =IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$8, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($C$1:C1, $A$2:$A$8), 0)),"")

Now fill your column headers for value1 , value2 and so on.

Finally write this formula in cell D2 and drag it to right and down.

> =IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,$C2,$B$2:$B$8,RIGHT(D$1,1))>0,RIGHT(D$1,1)*1,"")